# Classification on multivariate time series

Tags: r, time-series, classification, python

My dataset:

- 121 individuals characterized by a categorical variable let’s say Y (so 121 values of Y)
- for each individual, I have 5 time series, let’s say X1, X2, X3, X4, X5.
- each time series contains 6000 points.

All the time series increase over time, with abrupt changes, and end with a plateau.

**I want to build a classification model to understand which time series (or features of the time series, like abrupt changes, or combination of these features) explain and then predict the best the variable Y.**

I am not used to work with time series, and I have found that the "Time series" analysis models are mostly around forecasting from existing data, and so I spent time looking for a clear procedure explaining how to handle this type of data for this specific purpose without much success.

What I have tested (see below) is always based on one time series (matrix of 121 × 6000) at once since I do not understand how to deal with several time series:

- unsupervised clustering of each time series (hclust and kmeans)
- a Discrete Wavelet Transform (DWT) to extract features and application of a decision tree on the extracted features. Here I do not understand how to interpret the features (wavelet coefficients and scaling coefficient) regard to the initial data.

Any help or recommendation for a tutorial will be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: This may be a bit more of a statistics question because you really need to understand the right model to use ant then you can  figure out what the right package to use.  I'm not sure what you are doing when you speak of clustering a time series.  More likely I think you need a mixed model where the variance component incorporates autocorrelation. It would possibly be helpful for you to show a tiny (maybe 10 or 15 rows of y and 2 or 3 time series),  But you might be better off on the cross-validated site.

Comment: Also you haven't made it totally clear if the value of Y can change for an individual, why are there only 121 values of Y rather than 121*6000. There are really different approaches depending on this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added an image in my post to make it clearer. I want to explain the Y variable ( wich can take as values: low, medium, high) by 5 times series of 6000 points each one. I have 121 values of Y (so 121 individuals) and for for each one 5*6000 points. So in tototal I have 121*5*6000 points